# Using shared_ptr with a const reference

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr

I need to make several `Worker` classes that have a pointer to an `Object` owned by the main program. This is in C++14

For reasons, the `Object` has to meet certain criteria - it has to have a deleted default constructor, its non-copyable, non-movable.  And I need to use smart pointers.

The main program will own the `Object`. Each worker class needs to read stuff from it

```
class Object
{
  Object() = delete;
  ~Object();

  // Non copyable
  Object(const Object &other) = delete;
  Object &operator=(const Object &other) = delete;

  // Non movable
  Object(Object &&other) = delete;
  Object &operator=(Object &&other) = delete;

  // Constructor
  explicit Object(double threshold);
};

class Worker
{
public:
  void initialize(const Object& obj)
  {
    // Option 1 - errors out, complains its non copyable
    object_ptr = std::make_shared<const Object>(obj);

    // Option 2
    object_ptr = std::shared_ptr<const Object>(&obj);

    // Option 3
    object_ptr = std::shared_ptr<const Object>(&obj, [](const Object*){});
  }

  void doSomething();

private:
  std::shared_ptr<const Object> object_ptr;
};

int main () 
{
  Object object;

  Worker worker1;
  Worker worker2;

  worker1.initialize(object);
  worker2.initialize(object);

  while(1)
  {
    // Main does stuff to Object

    worker1.doSomething();
    worker2.doSomething();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What's the best way to initialize the pointer inside of `Worker`?

Comment: Yes you can, @DietrichEpp, shared_ptr doesn't actually have to hold onto a shared reference. You can fake it with the aliasing constructor. You never should, but you can.

Comment: If the workers aren't participating in the ownership of the object why not just have them keep a reference to the object?  If you need to be able to init the reference after constructing the worker (or need to be able to change the reference) then this might be a legitimate use case for a non-smart, raw pointer. Otherwise it seems you're adding complexity for no gain.

Comment: It seems like your pattern requires using shared_ptr in the main program and weak_ptr in your workers. Why are you passing the object by const reference if you want smartpointers?

Answer (score 0):

I personally would do this

```
class Worker
{
public:
    void initialize(const Object& obj)
    {
        object_ptr = &obj;
    }
private:
    const Object* object_ptr = nullptr;
};
```

A raw pointer indicates non-ownership, which is exactly what the situation is.

If you must use a `shared_ptr`, there is no way around passing in one as an argument, `shared_ptr` has more data associated with it than just the managed object.

```
class Worker
{
public:
    void initialize(std::shared_ptr<const Object> p)
    {
        swap(object_ptr, p);
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<const Object> object_ptr;
};

int main()
{
    auto obj = std::make_shared<const Object>();
    //...
}
```

A `shared_ptr` means exactly what it says: the resource is **shared**. To pass around a `shared_ptr` is to proclaim there are **multiple** owners and the resource is common to all of them, aka the resource must outlive any of them.

Note how you have the object **on the stack** (or rather, have automatic storage duration) which is indicative that this resource is not in fact, owned by the workers. By definition of the workers, we know automatically that the object will outlive the workers, and this is by far superior to using `shared_ptr`s.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use shared_ptr's [aliasing constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;
```

This allows you to create a shared_ptr, but not actually own the object, so the stored value is not actually reference counted. This means the referenced object must remain valid externally.

In this case, just set initialize to be:

```
void initialize(const Object& obj)
  {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<const Object> my_ptr;
    object_ptr = my_ptr(my_ptr(), &obj);
  }
```

It's a hack, and it will fake a true shared_ptr, but it will work. For a self-contained, external example, try:

```
#include <memory>

struct x_t
{
    x_t() = delete;
    x_t(const x_t&) = delete;
    x_t(x_t&&) = delete;
    x_t(double y) {}
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<const x_t> x_t_ptr;
    const x_t x(5);

    x_t_ptr ptr = x_t_ptr(x_t_ptr(), &x);

    return 0;
}
```

I should really warn you that you should not do this, since you will appear to have memory safety when you have no such thing. Basically, you're making a guarantee that you have memory safety, while then effectively using a raw pointer to a temporary object. This is **very** dangerous.

Comment: *"This allows you to create a shared_ptr, but not actually own the object"* no it isn't, what do you think *alias* here means?

Comment: Because it's aliasing a pointer to an object it doesn't own? Like, for example, here:
http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/04/25/shared-ptr-aliasing-constructor/

Comment: I think I understand why you said what you said. But the wording is so extremely misleading, if you wrote something like what your link said, there would be no confusion

Comment: It doesn't own the memory. It does not have ownership over the object's lifetime. It does not manage the object's lifetime. It does not "own" the object, it points to it. It is aliasing a raw pointer. It's not misleading, it's accurate. @PasserBy

Comment: No, its not accurate, for one thing, you failed to mention it owns another object, that is, it is managing another objects lifetime. You also failed to mention the primary use case of such a thing is to manage an object while pointing to its sub-object, which is indirectly owning the sub-object. You later said it is a hack to alias with an empty `shared_ptr`, which is totally correct, but doesn't make sense without the aforementioned context

Comment: It is, for all intents and purposes, a raw pointer here. Especially, a raw pointer to a temporary object. That is what it is. It just so happens to have a use for certain interfaces. I consider that a hack: it is the illusion of managed memory (via the interface) with none of the practicality of it. It works, but it is a hack. The shared_ptr does not own the object, it does not even manage it's own control block in my example. What you have said is "extremely misleading", I might add. @PasserBy